# Adding a password to one page of a blogdown site

Tags: r, password-protection, bookdown, blogdown

Is it possible to password protect one page of a website made using `R blogdown`, published using the free version of Netlify?

If not, it it possible to host a password protected RMD file on a blogdown website? I tried using the `encryptedRmd` package but I don't think it's meant for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to add basic password protection for one page on my website using [Brent Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11437205/bs93)'s `pagecryptr` [package](https://github.com/brentscott93/pagecryptr), which is a R-wrapper for [PageCrypt](https://www.maxlaumeister.com/pagecrypt/). The set up is very simple thanks to the R package.

1. Create the password protected version of the RMD file, knit it to HTML, and save it somewhere (literally anywhere, but I put it on my private repository on GitHub). We'll call this file `password.html`.
2. Name the page you want to password protect in your TOML file. Mine looks like this:

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Portfolio"
    url = "/Portfolio/"
```

Note that you do not need to create a RMD or HTML file for this page because we'll be using `pagecryptr` to create it.

3. Install `pagecryptr`

```
install.packages("drat")
drat::addRepo("brentscott93")
install.packages("pagecryptr")
library(pagecryptr)
```

4. In a different R script, run `pagecryptr` to password protect the file:

```
if(interactive()){
 file <- "~/password.html"
 pagecryptr(file, "password123", out_file = "~/content/Portfolio.html")
}
```

Notice how `pagecryptr` is taking the file we want to password protect (`password.html`) and writing HTML for it that corresponds to the page we created in our TOML (`Portfolio.html`). The second argument contains the password you want to use for the website (in this example, it's `password123`).

Commit `Portfolio.html` to GitHub and you will have a password protected page on your website!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you want to do is a question for the Netlify community. Once a blogdown site is created, it is just a static site, and you can use any Netlify feature you want, I'd guess. (It appears to be possible: https://answers.netlify.com/t/password-protection-for-a-single-html-page/31117/7 )

Comment: This is great, but I believe it requires a paid plan

Comment: As I said, this is a question for Netlify community. Nevertheless, "HTTP Auth is not available on the free plan," but the instructions I sent you to were for "Role-based redirects." I have no idea whether role-based redirects will work for your use case, but if you have followup questions, please find a way to ask the Netlify community.

Comment: I found a way to do it using the `pagecryptr` package. Should work with any server.